# regex for parsing imports in other scripts?

Tags: python, regex

We have a large library of custom scripts (300+) on a network share and I have been cleaning up a few deprecated modules and I need to know what scripts import these so I can point them to the new modules. Therefore, I'm trying to come up with a reg ex that will allow me to search for any deprecated module.

so for example, I have 2 deprecated modules (among many) called `sql_db` and `sql_server`, so I need to report what scripts may be importing these, but I'm having trouble writing a "catch all" regex that would find `sql_db` in the following scenarios (and any other import statements I may be overlooking):

```
from sql_db import *
import sql_db
import os, sql_db, other_module
import sql_db, os
import os,sql_db
```

I am terrible with regular expressions but I feel like I'm pretty close in this test:

```
import re

tests = ['import test',
         'import sql_db',
         'import test, sql_db',
         'import sql_db, test',
         'from sql_db import *',
         'import bmi, sql_db, os, sys',
         'from test import os, sys',
         'from sql_d import b',
         'import a,b,c',
         'import sql_db,test,os',
         '    import sys, sql_db1, test, os',
         'import sys,sql_db,test,os'] 


pat = re.compile('\s*(import|from) (.*)(sql_db)(.*)')
for test in tests:
    print test, '| ', pat.match(test) is not None
```

This almost works, but is a little too greedy as it will return true when a module is named `sql_db1` or one that has any characters after `sql_db`.

Here are the results (note the failure in the second to last test):

```
import test |  False
import sql_db |  True
import test, sql_db |  True
import sql_db, test |  True
from sql_db import * |  True
import bmi, sql_db, os, sys |  True
from test import os, sys |  False
from sql_d import b |  False
import a,b,c |  False
import sql_db,test,os |  True
    import sys, sql_db1, test, os |  True  #should be false but is returning true for sql_db1
import sys,sql_db,test,os |  True
```

I know it is because I have the greedy `(.*)` after `(sql_db)`, but how can I make find that part explicitly?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you take a look at the `ast` module? You can use it to parse those scripts. With a custom visitor you could extract all "import" and "from" imports.

Comment: I have never heard of this...I'll check it out, no sense in reinventing the wheel!  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\b` to look for a word boundary before & after (sql_db):

```
\s*(import|from)(.*)\b(sql_db)\b
```

This will not match with sql_db1 because sql_db does not end in a word boundary -- it ends in a 1. Commas *are* considered word boundaries, so it works with the rest of your examples as well. Feel free to test it at http://regexr.com/

Comment: @Rawing Good call! Edited.

Comment: This works perfectly now, thanks!  I missed the `\b` sequence in the docs.